# The data in A "id" is not printing

Tags: vba, dom, shdocvw.internetexplorer

i am trying this

```
Sub JJ()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim hdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim ha As String

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=DIVISLAB"
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set hdoc = IE.document
ha = hdoc.getElementById("preOpenFp").innerText
Debug.Print ha
End Sub
```

Please suggest any solution for that.
the point is in image.[image: The point and data i need is marked.]

Comment: this is VBA, VB or .NET, not JAVA or JSON related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read the data from the Pre-Open Markt you have to change the url as follows `https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=DIVISLAB#info-preopenmkt`.Try this code.

```
Sub JJ()
Dim IE
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Dim hdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim ha As String
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=DIVISLAB#info-preopenmkt"

Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do While IE.Busy And Not IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))
Set hdoc = IE.document

ha = hdoc.getElementById("preOpenIep").innerText

Debug.Print (ha)

End Sub
```

Comment: The output is "-" when i am running the code pls suggest any idea.

Comment: I edited my code with a new line: `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))`

Comment: The problem is still. output is "-"

Comment: I don't know. I haven't this problem using Internet Explorer as browser. Try to wait more `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))` or try to stop the function with debug after `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))`.

Comment: thanks pizzettix. Do have any idea for XML coding for same work. to make it faster